# Sieve-filter email with ambiguous message content

Tags: email, filtering, dovecot, sieve-language

From an external monitoring service I receive emails with message **bodies** containing random amounts of warnings:

```
foo
warning X
bar
warning X
...
```

Or:

```
warning X
warning Y
foo
warning X
bar
warning Z
...
```

*Warning X is irrelevant, but all other warnings are important. X is a known type - all others can be anything.*

If an email contains only `warning X` lines, I can safely trash it. The sieve script would be straightforward:

```
if body :contains "warning X" {
      fileinto :create "INBOX.Trash";
}
```

However, when a message contains `warning X` **and** other warnings, the script would trash the message and I would miss all other warnings in it, which is unacceptable.

**How can I discard all messages that exclusively contain warnings of type X?**

---

If I had regex I could check for something like `"warning [^X]"`, but so far I am unable to find any way to express this in sieve.

The next thing that came to mind was comparing the amount of occurrences of `"warning X"` against just `"warning "`. If they were equal, it would mean that every warning was in fact of type `X`. However, the `:count` expression doesn't seem to work on message bodies and also seems to only compare against hard-coded integers.

Comment: This isn't "ambiguous", just more complex than the basic Sieve syntax allows you to express.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting the question I realized that I [do have regex](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/id/draft-ietf-sieve-regex-01.html):

```
require ["body", "fileinto", "mailbox", "regex"];

if not body :regex "warning [^X]" {
    fileinto :create "INBOX.Trash";
}
```

This script appears to have the desired effect.